# How Do I Connect A UITabBarController To The App Delegate In A View-Based App (Part 1)?

Tags: xcode, view, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, outlet

I'm attempting to convert my view based application to a tab bar application. I'm having trouble connecting a new UITabBarController to the App Delegate. It doesn't give me the option. I must be missing some sort of connection along the way.

I added a Tab Bar Controller to my "MainViewController.xib". From most of the things I've read, I should be connecting to the "MainWindow.xib," only problem is that I've got both iPhone and iPad formats setup from the View-Based Application so I'm looking for a way to connect it universally (so I don't have to recreate it for both the iPhone and iPad formats separately).

I created an outlet in my MillersAppAppDelegate.h file (and synthesized it all correctly) but the outlet that I created for the Tab Bar Controller does not appear as an option when I attempt to connect it in the Interface Builder (I'm assuming this is because I haven't correctly connecting the Tab Bar Controller to the delegate in the first place).

I'd like to just stop here and learn this first step so it doesn't get too confusing yet:

1) How do I connect my new Tab Bar Controller to the App Delegate in a View-Based App?

2) How do I then subsequently connect my Tab Bar Controller (that was created and synthesized in the App Delegate) to the UITabBarController?

---

I've looked at other people's questions regarding this type of thing and most of the reactions are "It's easier to just start a new tab bar app and transfer the content over." I still want to be able to learn how to do this though, it'll help me learn the language of X Code and Objective C better by pushing through it and make me well versed and better in the end (as it will for the others with similar questions). Thanks for putting up with my beginner questions, I'm still learning!